# html wrap line containing text form and file selection

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i am working on a website which has a line of text saying:

"Input a discos url [TEXT INPUT FORM] or choose files [FILE SELECTION INPUT]"

I have these elements written up here:

http://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/6o3gq4nc/2/

I could only get both elements to be displayed in one single neat line by adding the

```
#inputOptions { 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    /* 
    overflow-wrap: break-word; */
    word-wrap: normal;
    
    
    }
```

css style code to my html doc, but now if i resize the page to be even thinner, the line dissapers.

Is there some way to make it so all my elements are included in one single, neat line, that also has a word-wrap feature for when the window gets re-sized?

thanks

Comment: Can you tell the width of the page(eg. 576px) at which the line disappears and which words are you exactly trying to wrap-up?

Comment: tried same code on Chrome based UC Web Browser, IE 11 and Mozilla Firefox, line not disappearing, everything working well. Which browser you using?